# interp1d with streaming data?

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I know that you can pass the data lists `x` and `y` to scipy's `interp1d` by reference. Does this mean I can add new data to it by simply modifying the inputs `x` and `y` in-place?

Ideally, I'm looking for something that will do the following efficiently:

1. It interpolates the value for some point we request.
2. Based on that interpolated value, we decide whether or not to obtain the 'true' value.
3. If the true value is obtained, we then want to **update the algorithm's knowledge** for future interpolations.

However, once the values are put into the interpolating algorithm, they are not presumed to change--new points can only be added. I *think* interp1d does some kind of fancy processing on the input data to make the lookup faster, but I'm not sure if that precludes adding to the data in-place. Please help!

Edit: Some of you will likely notice that this has a lot in common with Metropolis-Hastings, however, steps 1-3 may not occur serially; hence I need a more abstract interpolation method to support asynchronous updates. If you know of any, suggestions, that would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simplest is to write your own interpolating object:

```
class Interpolator:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        if len(x)!=len(y):
            raise BaseException("Lists must have the same length")
        self.xlist=x
        self.ylist=y 
        self.len=len(x)
    def find_x_index(self,x0): # find index i such that xlist[i]<=x0<xlist[i+1]
        a,b=0,self.len-1 
        while b-a>1:
            m=int((b+a)/2)
            if x0<self.xlist[m]:
                b=m
            else:
                a=m
        return a
    def add_point(self,x,y): # add a new point 
        if x<self.xlist[0]:
            self.xlist.insert(0,x)
            self.ylist.insert(0,y)
        elif x>self.xlist[-1]:
            self.xlist.append(x)
            self.ylist.append(y)
        else:
            i=self.find_x_index(x)
            self.xlist.insert(i+1,x)
            self.ylist.insert(i+1,y)
        self.len+=1
    def interpolate(self,x0): # interpolates y value for x0
        if x0<self.xlist[0] or x0>self.xlist[-1]:
            raise BaseException("Value out of range")
        a=self.find_x_index(x0)
        eps=(x0-self.xlist[a])/(self.xlist[a+1]-self.xlist[a]) # interpolation
        return (eps*self.ylist[a+1]+(1-eps)*self.ylist[a])

itp=Interpolator([1,2,3],[1,3,4])
print(itp.interpolate(1.6))
itp.add_point(1.5,3)
print(itp.interpolate(1.6))
```

The key point is to always keep the x list sorted, so that you can use dichotomy which is a logarithmic complexity algorithm.

Remark: in `add_point`, you should check that there aren't two same `x` values with different `y`

Comment: This is an excellent solution -- I actually ended up doing something very much like this, using Python's `bisect`